# Extra spaces between 3 columns of DIV

Tags: html, css

[My fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hqscru7u/2/)

Not sure why when I apply border, it doesn't seem right, the border should have no spacing. Something is wrong but can't debug, need help.

```
<div id="DIV_1">
  <div id="DIV_2">
    PayPal
  </div>
  <div id="DIV_3">
    Online Banking
  </div>
  <div id="DIV_4">
    Debit/Credit Card
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem that arrises when you use `inline-block` is that `whitespace` in HTML becomes `visual space` on screen.

A simple solution would to set `font-size: 0;` over parent element and specify required `font-size` for its children.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#DIV_1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 880px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 440px 21px;
  transform-origin: 440px 21px;
  background: rgb(67, 82, 85) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 0;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}
/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 290.391px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  transform-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  border-top: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-left: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
/*#DIV_2*/

#DIV_3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 290.391px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  transform-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  background: rgb(204, 0, 51) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
/*#DIV_3*/

#DIV_4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 290.391px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  transform-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  border-top: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-right: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
/*#DIV_4*/
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
  <div id="DIV_2">
    PayPal
  </div>
  <div id="DIV_3">
    Online Banking
  </div>
  <div id="DIV_4">
    Debit/Credit Card
  </div>
</div>
```

Refer [**Remove Whitespace Between Inline-Block Elements**](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

I just updated your fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hqscru7u/3/) and i just deleted some borders of your `div's` to see if its correct.

there are many ways in solving this problem. With regards to your side. I just deleted the spaces between your `div_2`,`div_3` and `div_4`.

for other solutions and furthen explaination. you can refer in this [**site**.](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a negative margin on each div.

```
div.yourClass {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added `border-right` and `left` of `1px` in your `div2` and `div4` and that was creating a issue, well you can aligning them properly using float:left, as below, And if you prefer to continue with your codes then just remove border of 1px from div2 and div4.

```
#DIV_1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 880px;
  perspective-origin: 440px 21px;
  transform-origin: 440px 21px;
  background: #111;
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 300 normal 16px / 22.8571px Lato, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  float:left;
}


/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  float:left;
  background:#ccc;
}


/*#DIV_2*/

#DIV_3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  perspective-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  transform-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  background: #f22;
  padding: 10px;
  float:left;
  }


/*#DIV_3*/

#DIV_4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  perspective-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  transform-origin: 145.188px 21px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  float:left;
  background:#f2f;
}
```